# Dropdown box not working in google chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, cakephp, google-chrome

I wanted to display a dropdown box on a popup on click event and i achieved in firefox.

```
$("#selectId").click(function(){
}

<select id="Team1" name="team1">
  <option value="">Please select an option</option>
  <option value="11">test1</option>
  <option value="12">test2</option>
  <option value="13">test3</option>
</select>
```

[Reference](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdCalendar/sample.php)

I could select the options in firefox. But i couldn't select the options in google chrome, event the dropdown is now showing up on clicking it. I tried to check it with “Inspect element” i could see the select and options there.
I don't know why...
Any help would be appreciated...
When I check with the google chrome console it shows this "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a bug with google chrome. It works with Firefox and i think it would work fine with IE too.

One solution could be to Adding 1px margin or padding to #menu makes it work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, it working in Firefox, IE and Opera but not in chrome. Even padding or margin didn't work...

Comment: Is there any possibility to over come this problem. cuz i need it very badly.